# AWS DescribeStacks action - can I limit to specific resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want create a policy that allows cloudformation:DescribeStacks but limited to only describe specific stacks and not all of them. My preference would be to limit to stacks that have a specific tag, and if that's not possible, limit to stacks with a name that starts with a certain perfix.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awscloudformation.html#awscloudformation-stack I think that should be possible. However everything I tried didn't work, I get permission denied response.

Here is what I tried:

1 -

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
}
```

1 Works, returns all stacks.

2 -

```
 {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:ResourceTag/my-tag": "*"
        }
    }
}
```

2 is getting the following error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/yyyy is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks

3 -

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
    ],
    "Resource": "my-specific-stack-id (ARN)" (tried also with just prefix and *)
}
```

3 - getting same error as 2

4 -

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
            "aws:TagKeys": "my-tag*"
        }
    }
}
```

4 is also getting the same error as 2 and 3.

Is that possible at all to do what I'm trying to do or does DescribeStacks only work with "Resource" : "*"? if the latter, the documentation is confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this. From your [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awscloudformation.html#awscloudformation-actions-as-permissions), `DescribeStacks` **does not support** any conditions:

[image]

From the same table, `aws:RequestTag/${TagKey}` works only with some actions, such as `UpdateStack`.

**Update**

Your policy with full resource is **correct**:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:stack/sandbox-noe3kx0sbw02bb/952c2af0-71d3-11eb-832b-06f0a0237781"
```

However, to use `DescribeStacks` operation you **must** specify a stack name `sandbox-noe3kx0sbw02bb`, e.g.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks  --stack-name sandbox-noe3kx0sbw02bb --region <region-of-stack>
```

You **can't** use the operation without stack name:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region <region-of-stack>
```

as you don't have permissions to describe all stacks. You can only describe that one specific stack.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcin for your prompt answer!
But, in the "Resource types" it does say that it supports stack* so why can't I limit like this:
"Resource": "my-specific-stack-id (ARN)" (tried also with just prefix and *)

Comment: @ShiraBendor You would have to provide full example. Its not clear what `"my-specific-stack-id (ARN)" (tried also with just prefix and *)` means.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Marcin. I mean to limit the resource (without condition).  Like this:  
  `{ "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "cloudformation:DescribeStacks" ], "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:stack/sandbox-noe3kx0sbw02bb/952c2af0-71d3-11eb-832b-06f0a0237781" }`      
 i.e I provided the exact resource ARN and I get permission denied.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcin, appreciate it. I accepted your helpful answer.